# How to query this JSONB?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

So I have a table

```
Node_Mapping(location_id:UUID, node_ids: jsonb)
```

The corresponding POJO for this is

```
class NodeMapping{
    UUID locationId;
    Set<String> nodeIds;
}
```

Example data in table is

```
UUID1 : ['uuid100', 'uuid101']
UUID2 : ['uuid103', 'uuid101']
```

So I want to make a query like, find out all the `locationIds` which contains this `List<String> : ['uuid100', 'uuid200', 'uuid300']`

Please help me to form the "IN" query with JSONB.

Also please help me to create a function/SP to take input this list of string and return the list of locationIds as an List/Set..

I tried the function but that fails.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_location_ids_for_seller(_seller_id text[])
   RETURNS TABLE(location_id text)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
 $func$
 BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT n.location_id::text
    FROM   node_mapping n
    WHERE  n.node_ids IN _seller_id;
 END
 $func$;
```

Comment: Can you please bring more precision about the criteria to select the locationIds : is it the list of locationIds whose node_ids (a) corresponds exactly to the list ['uuid100', 'uuid200', 'uuid300'] :: jsonb (b) contains the list ['uuid100', 'uuid200', 'uuid300'] :: jsonb (c) contains one or more elements of the list ['uuid100', 'uuid200', 'uuid300'] :: jsonb (d) ...

Comment: Basically, ['uuid100', 'uuid200', 'uuid300'] it is the list of node ids, the content of this list can belong to various location_id(s). eg., location1UUID - ['uuid100'], location2UUID-['uuid200', 'uuid300'] ..

Now, my objective is, that I get a list of randomised nodeIds as given in example above, my output should be ['Location1UUID', 'Location2UUID']

Comment: And answer to your question will be, (c).

Answer (score 1):

The query to retrieve the node_ids which contain one or more elements of the list _seller_id :: text[] is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_location_ids_for_seller(_seller_id text[])
   RETURNS TABLE(location_id text)
   LANGUAGE sql AS
 $func$
    SELECT n.location_id::text
    FROM   node_mapping n
    WHERE  n.node_ids :: jsonb ?| _seller_id ;
 $func$;
```